# Use librdkafka in a C++ project (VS2013)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, apache-kafka, lib

I'm trying to use [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka), I had a hard time compling it, but I think I manage to do it, here are the generated file after compilation :

[image: output file]

Now I've been trying for hours but I cannot successfully link it into a C++ Project on Visual Studio 2013.

Can someone explain what do I have to do with those files ?

Good evening everyone.

Answer (score 0):

From your Visual Studio project you should reference the [librdkafka.redist](https://www.nuget.org/packages/librdkafka.redist/) NuGet package.
After NuGet restore your project should be automatically set up to link with librdkafka.

See [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/tree/master/win32) for an example that does this.